# Adwords Contact Form Tracking

Tags: html, google-ads-api, pay-per-click

We have a senario whereby which we are tracking a contact forms submission via Adwords Conversion tracking code and assigning that as a PPC conversion.

This is a lead generation website; therefore the issue coming to light is that they have good SEO and receive a large amount of contact form submissions organically.

We need to find out the success of contact form conversions via the PPC and can then account that to ROI; therefore we receive a Bc on the contact form submissions and would like to know if there is a way in which we could tag all PPC contact form submissions details i.e. a email address etc and then we can separate those from SEO form submissions and then get them to look at those PPC enquiries only and feedback on the success.

Does anyone know of a solution, or the best way to attack this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Analytics? It should be able to determine the source of your leads so you can break them out into leads by SEO and leads by PPC.

Or are you trying to figure out the exact traffic source of each individual lead you receive in an email. I've used a tool called http://convertable.com which does exactly this since Google Analytics doesn't really track beyond the initial contact form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Did you hear that AdWords launched a conversion import feature and API late last year?  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en

The case they talk about a lot is lead conversions.  Here's how it works.  Put simply, you capture the click ID from every ad click.  If one of those people goes on to submit a lead, you store the click ID (called a GCLID) along with the lead's information.

Then, if the lead goes of to become qualified or even becomes a customer, you send the GCLID back to AdWords along with the date/time it converted, and AdWords records it as an actual conversion.  They you can get reporting, or use their bid automation, to optimize for these.

Does that help?

Jon

Answer (score 0):

> We have a senario whereby which we are tracking a contact forms
>   submission via Adwords Conversion tracking code and assigning that as
>   a PPC conversion.

Why don't you just track the contact forms submissions as a analytics goal? if you want to add a value to them you can just give a fixed amount in analytics.

> This is a lead generation website; therefore the issue coming to light
>   is that they have good SEO and receive a large amount of contact form
>   submissions organically.
>   We need to find out the success of contact form conversions via the PPC and can then account that to ROI;

You can look at Source/Medium in the Acquisition section, or in the Conversions section of analytics or create a custom report with this information.

> therefore we receive a Bc on the contact form submissions and would like to know if there is a way in which we could tag all PPC contact form submissions details i.e. a email address etc and then we can separate those from SEO form submissions and then get them to look at those PPC enquiries only and feedback on the success.

you can associate email accounts to source/medium by tracking utm codes in the backend so that every time there is a submission you would have saved the utm_source and utm_medium parameters from the URL submission request (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en).

Another way of doing this is using a fremium tool like KISS metrics - https://www.kissmetrics.com/ or mixpanel - https://mixpanel.com